# Light wiring - wires snapped when disassembling

Tags: wiring, light-fixture

I was taking down a light to replace it for a newer one for my wife. The wires coming out of the ceiling are ancient and they snapped as I pulled down the housing (incredibly brittle). Now I do not know which one was where.

I thought that I had it correctly re-wired, but now I cannot get the light to turn on. The pictures of the fixture are wired how I **think** it should be. Are they correct?

I re-attached the cables where I thought they should go under the assumption that:

Brown/Red = Live
Black = Neutral

I labelled in red where I attached the cables from the light to the fitting.

The light I want to attach:

[image: The cable from the light I want to fit]

The fitting I am attaching to:

[image: The fitting]

[image: The fitting]

Comment: (1) Where on the planet are you (2) How old do you think the building wiring might be (3) do you have a voltmeter or any electrical test equipment

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri His profile says "Germany".

Comment: 1. Yes Germany. 2. Hard to tell, this is a rented house - likely built in the 60s. 3. Unfortunately no, that will be high on my to-do list after this though!

Comment: It appears you have them correctly identified. A non contact voltage tester will show you the hot lead. Are you sure the lamp is good? If you were doing the work with just the light switch off did the breaker trip? You mentioned brittle wiring , the wires could be shorted where it goes through the small hole in the ceiling

Comment: That could be. I'll buy a multimeter on my way home tomorrow. Then I can actually test it.

Comment: Well, there appears to be a circuit being made when I use my new meter. It detects 12V when I hold the buttons on it (touching contacts) and 24V intermittently when I hold it on the contacts without touching the buttons and wiggle a bit. It all looks a bit shifty if I'm honest with you. I'm going to get a professional to have a look at it.